# GWT Compatibility issue with OPEN LIBERTY Vresion 23.0.0_0601

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, open-liberty

I have upgraded the Open liberty server version (v 23.0.0_601) in for my application.
when we have deployed with the following combination of
JDK  version 8.0.372_01 and OPEN LIBERTY version 23.0.0_0601
we encountered the following error :

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWX60.png)
1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'L')
at YKc (cockpit-0.js:5701:31)
at ZKc.$Kc [as Mg] (cockpit-0.js:10459:24086)
at qVb.sVb [as Te] (cockpit-0.js:10455:10065)
at Pw (cockpit-0.js:6863:79)
at ax.bx [as Re] (cockpit-0.js:10454:7250)
at XMLHttpRequest.eval (cockpit-0.js:6343:65)
at Uj (cockpit-0.js:4445:29)
at Xj (cockpit-0.js:6053:44)
at XMLHttpRequest.eval (cockpit-0.js:6369:46)
YKc @ cockpit-0.js:5701
$Kc @ c

I have tried below combination of jdk and open liberty, both combination's
are not working.

I have upgraded the Open liberty server version (v 23.0.0_601) in for my application.
when we have deployed with the following combination of
JDK  version 8.0.372_01 and OPEN LIBERTY version 23.0.0_0601
we encountered the following error

NOTE:
the application is developed with GWT 2.10.0/2.8.0 version .

Is Liberty Version 23.0.0.601 is supported GWT and which version GWT is supports.

Comment: I do not know OPEN LIBERTY. The stacktrace is telling you, that the client has problems evaluating the respnse from the server. I think, it would be a good idea to take a look at the network tab and check the payload of the response.